Question on rotational dynamics
My book states that it's convienient to apply torque equation $\tau=I \alpha$ on
instantaneous axis of rotation and centre of mass.
My question is: why it is so?
And how can we apply torque equation on points other than those two that are mentioned?

I'm not exactly sure on this, but I'll attempt to answer:
By taking your reference point to be the instantaneous axis of rotation, you can often ignore the translational motion in your calculations, as by doing so, you are assuming that at that instant, the body is purely rotating about that point.
By taking your reference point to be the center of mass, if your shape is one of the basic shapes, you can just use the base formula for the moment of inertia, without having to edit it using formulas like Parallel Axis Theorem.
You can apply the torque equation on other points, but you would have to change you formula for moment of inertia accordingly. For example, if you have a disk, you may know that it's formula is 1/2 MR2. However, that is only the moment of inertia about the centre of mass. If let's say you want to take the reference point at an arbitrary point a distance d away from the disc, your moment of inertia is actually 1/2 MR2 + Md2.
These are just the main reasons that I can think of right now, I'm sure that there are other reasons as well that I might have missed out.
